# Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed golang multi stage dockerizatio

Tags: docker, go

this is the error im getting while dockerizing my golang code

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/app/app": stat /app/app: no such file or directory: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.21.5 AS build


WORKDIR /app


COPY go.mod go.sum ./


RUN go mod download


COPY . .

# Build the Go application
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /app


FROM scratch


WORKDIR /app


COPY --from=build /app /app


EXPOSE 4000

# Set the entrypoint for the container to run the binary
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/app"]
```

**However i managed to fix it by not using the multistage build and now my DockerFile looks like this**

```
FROM golang:1.21.5


WORKDIR /app


COPY go.mod go.sum ./


RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /app/app


EXPOSE 4000


ENTRYPOINT ["/app/app"]
```

There has to be a solution right am i doing something wrong while using multi stage dockerization?

Answer (score 1):

`go build -o /app` don't create binary into directory app, but create binary `/app`.

Solution:

```
FROM golang:1.21.5 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /app/app


FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /app /app
EXPOSE 4000
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/app"]
```